# Multi value attributes in Rails ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a Property model that should contain multiple values (just Strings). With Rails/ActiveRecord it seems that I have to create a new model (and a new table) for those values (like PropertyValue). As every one of those values just stores one String the PropertyValue only need one attribute (like value).
I don't like that idea cause to access one of those values I now have to call property.values[0].value and that looks a bit ugly.
Is there a nicer solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `serialize` method

```
class Property < ...
  serialize :value, ::Array
end
```

`value` array will be stored as string in `properties` table and you can access it as normal array: `property.value[3]`.

More details in [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize).